# My python tkinter program will only show the first three buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The program is meant to show 7 buttons but only shows the first three. I would appreciate some help, I'm trying to make a catalog program that writes files and text in those files. It works without tkinter, but the buttons arent showing up. I wrote the seven buttons and they worked originally but they have since stopped working. I don't know the problem since this is my first time with tkinter.

```
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Catalog 2020")

button = tk.Button(frame,
                    text = "Make New File",
                    command=answer1)
button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

button2 = tk.Button(frame, 
                    text = "Edit File", 
                    command = answer2)
button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
button3 = tk.Button(frame, 
                    text = "Append Data", 
                    command = answer3)
button3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
button4 = tk.Button(frame, 
                    text = "Read File", 
                    command = answer4)
button4.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
button5 = tk.Button(frame, 
                    text = "Delete File", 
                    command = answer5)
button5.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
button6 = tk.Button(frame, 
                    text = "Tell me a Joke", 
                    command = answer6)
button6.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
buttonquit = tk.Button(frame, 
                text="QUIT", 
                fg="red",
                command=quit)
buttonquit.pack
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove `root.geometry(...)`

Comment: Welcome to SO :) . I ran your code as is (just added parentheses after `buttonquit.pack` ) , and I can clearly see all the 7 buttons on the GUI. Without making even one slight change.

Comment: I just realized that I was opening an older version. I feel stupid. Thank you all.

Comment: @PSSolanki: that seems impossible. the first button references `answer1` but `answer1` is undefined.

Comment: It wouldnt let me add all the code but trust me I defined all of the variables.

Comment: @BryanOakley Of course I would change that 'cause that doesn't have anything to do with geometry and layouts. In fact I made all the commands say `command=answer` for every button and just defined the `answer` function to do nothing. Moreover as the OP said, problem was not with code posted here, it was with some older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `root.geometry('500x500')` your asking your window to be '500x500' , remove that line to fit all the window with the widgets. Also you forgot to say `()` with the `pack` of last  button, like `buttonquit.pack()` or you wont see that button too.

Comment: strange that I'm able to see all the 7 buttons without tweaking the geometry values, using the OP's code as is. Just for a change, added parentheses after `.pack` in second last line.

Comment: honestly kinda weird

Comment: @GraesonBrickner Hmmm yes strange, did this solution work?

Comment: Yeah it did, but do you think that there is any way for me to make it all GUI based because right now I have it as some in gui and some in command line. Full code here:https://github.com/catalog-crypto/catalog2020

Comment: @GraesonBrickner You can ask a new Q about it, but mainly its just basics of tkinter, to use `Label` and `Entry` widgets, it might gets ruled off this community